# Calculating training loss in linear regression

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-regression, loss-function, loss

Here is my linear regression code:

```
class linear_regression_glove(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, len_voxels, len_classes):
        super(linear_regression_glove, self).__init__()
        
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(len_voxels, size_embDim)
    
    def forward(self, X):
        out = self.linear(X)
        return out
    

def fit_linear_reg_glove(DS_train, test_X, which_case, fold_no, p_t):
    
    loader_train = DataLoader(DS_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    
    model = linear_regression_glove(size_vox, size_embDim)
    model.to(torch.device(device))
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss() 
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learningRate)
    training_loss_list = []
    
    for epoch in range(MAX_EPOCH):
        if(epoch % 10 == 0):
            print("epoch: %d / %d" % (epoch + 1, MAX_EPOCH))
        
        for i, sampled_batch in enumerate(loader_train):
            X_train     = sampled_batch["X"]
            y_emb_train = sampled_batch["y_emb"]

            
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                X_train = Variable(torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float32).cuda())
                y_emb_train = Variable(torch.tensor(y_emb_train, dtype=torch.int64).cuda())
            else:
                X_train     = torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
                y_emb_train = torch.tensor(y_emb_train, dtype=torch.int64).cuda()
            
            # Clear gradient buffers because we don't want any gradient from previous epoch to carry forward, dont want to cummulate gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            
            outputs = 0
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                outputs = model(X_train.to(device))
            else:
                outputs = model(X_train)
            
            loss = 0
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                loss = criterion(outputs, y_emb_train.float().to(device))
            else:
                loss = criterion(outputs, y_emb_train.float().to(device))
            
           
            training_loss_list.append(loss.item())
            #print(loss)
            # get gradients w.r.t to parameters
            loss.backward()

            # update parameters
            optimizer.step()
    
            

            #print(X_train.shape, y_emb_train.shape, y_hot_train.shape) #torch.Size([32, 1957]) torch.Size([32, 300]) torch.Size([32, 291])
     
    print("training loss shape: ", len(training_loss_list))
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), results_dir + '/weights_' + which_case + '_' +  str(fold_no) + '_' + p_t)
    
    test_X_torch = torch.tensor(test_X, dtype=torch.float32)
    
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        return (model(test_X_torch.float().cuda()), training_loss_list, training_loss_list) 
    else:
        return (model(test_X_torch.float()), training_loss_list, training_loss_list)
```

My question is about getting the training loss and plotting it. I am feeding my input data as batches to the model. As a result, if my input divides into `n` batches and I have `m` epochs, my training loss list will consist of `n*m`. However, I have a feeling there is something wrong with plotting this to examine the training value.

Should I get the loss in each loss after training all batches were finished for the whole data? Or is this the correct way?

Somehow like this (I have added #new comments on the new lines compared to the above code):

```
class linear_regression_glove(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, len_voxels, len_classes):
        super(linear_regression_glove, self).__init__()
        
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(len_voxels, size_embDim)
    
    def forward(self, X):
        out = self.linear(X)
        return out
    

def fit_linear_reg_glove(DS_train, test_X, which_case, fold_no, p_t):
    
    loader_train = DataLoader(DS_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    
    model = linear_regression_glove(size_vox, size_embDim)
    model.to(torch.device(device))
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss() 
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learningRate)
    training_loss_list = []
    
    for epoch in range(MAX_EPOCH):
        if(epoch % 10 == 0):
            print("epoch: %d / %d" % (epoch + 1, MAX_EPOCH))
        
        for i, sampled_batch in enumerate(loader_train):
            X_train     = sampled_batch["X"]
            y_emb_train = sampled_batch["y_emb"]

            
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                X_train = Variable(torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float32).cuda())
                y_emb_train = Variable(torch.tensor(y_emb_train, dtype=torch.int64).cuda())
            else:
                X_train     = torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
                y_emb_train = torch.tensor(y_emb_train, dtype=torch.int64).cuda()
            
            # Clear gradient buffers because we don't want any gradient from previous epoch to carry forward, dont want to cummulate gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            
            outputs = 0
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                outputs = model(X_train.to(device))
            else:
                outputs = model(X_train)
            
            loss = 0
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                loss = criterion(outputs, y_emb_train.float().to(device))
            else:
                loss = criterion(outputs, y_emb_train.float().to(device))
            
           
            training_loss_list.append(loss.item())
            #print(loss)
            # get gradients w.r.t to parameters
            loss.backward()

            # update parameters
            optimizer.step()
    
            
        outputs_train = model(training_data_all.to(device)) #new
        loss_to_add = criterion(outputs_train, y_emb_train_all.float().to(device)) #new
        training_loss_list.append(loss_to_add) #new
        
    print("training loss shape: ", len(training_loss_list))
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), results_dir + '/weights_' + which_case + '_' +  str(fold_no) + '_' + p_t)
    
    test_X_torch = torch.tensor(test_X, dtype=torch.float32)
    
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        return (model(test_X_torch.float().cuda()), training_loss_list, training_loss_list) 
    else:
        return (model(test_X_torch.float()), training_loss_list, training_loss_list)
```

Comment: Are you sure your linear_regression_glove is correct? You now have a linear regression that takes len_voxels inputs and size_embDim outputs. I think size_embDim should be changed to len_classes.

Comment: I want to predict glove vector models from my input data. So it is not classification